# Размещение элеметов в HBox

Tags: java, javafx

Здравствуйте, как в коде сделать так чтобы элемент Label был размешен в HBox снизу, и при растягивании окна менял свое положение?

Answer (score 1):

Для данной реализации `hBox` тебе не подойдет. Используй другие контейнеры. В твоем случае, хорошим выбором будет `BorderPane`, и `label` ты помещаешь снизу, т.е. `borderPane.setBottom(label)`

Answer (score 1):

Скажу пример при реализации через FXML. У HBox есть параметр Alignment, там нужно выбрать один из тех параметров, которые начинаются на BOTTOM_. В Scene Builder он идет первым во вкладке Properties.

Но если вам надо ТОЛЬКО один Label внизу, а все остальное сверху - то тогда только разместить вне HBox и маяться с версткой (Constrains) или паковать в какой-то другой контейнер